# hide gridlines on a .doc generated by php

Tags: php, ms-word, docx

I'm generating .doc with php using this code below.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    header("Cache-Control: ");// leave blank to avoid IE errors
    header("Pragma: ");// leave blank to avoid IE errors
    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
    header("content-disposition: attachment;filename=rapport.doc"); 
    ?>
    <html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
    xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
    xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name=ProgId content=Word.Document>
    <meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 9">
    <meta name=Originator content="Microsoft Word 9">
    <!--[if !mso]>
    <style>
    v\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
    o\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
    w\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
    .shape {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
    </style>
    <![endif]-->
    <title>title</title>
    <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
     <w:WordDocument>
      <w:View>Print</w:View>
      <w:DoNotHyphenateCaps/>
      <w:PunctuationKerning/>
      <w:DrawingGridHorizontalSpacing>9.35 pt</w:DrawingGridHorizontalSpacing>
      <w:DrawingGridVerticalSpacing>9.35 pt</w:DrawingGridVerticalSpacing>
     </w:WordDocument>
    </xml><![endif]-->
    <style>
    body{font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px;}
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table><tr><td>content</td></tr></table>
    </body>
    </html>
</php>
```

I'm looking for the way to hide the table gridlines.
When I open a dock generated by word - disabling gridlines - I founded this :

```
<w:tbl><w:tblPr><w:tblStyle w:val="Grille"/>
```

Can anybody tell me if I can this ?
Thanks,
Michel

Answer (score 0):

There are two different things: the table *borders*, which can be set for each table in the XML (see an example below) and a "view gridlines" option, which is an application setting that allows the user to see the table cell structure even when there are no visible borders. The "view gridlines" option is an application and cannot be specified in the XML.

For "no border lines" you need XML along the following lines, under the relevant

```
<w:tbl><w:tblPr>
```

element:

```
<w:tblBorders>
  <w:top w:val="none" w:sz="0" w:space="0" w:color="auto" />
  <w:left w:val="none" w:sz="0" w:space="0" w:color="auto" />
  <w:bottom w:val="none" w:sz="0" w:space="0" w:color="auto" />
  <w:right w:val="none" w:sz="0" w:space="0" w:color="auto" />
  <w:insideH w:val="none" w:sz="0" w:space="0" w:color="auto" />
  <w:insideV w:val="none" w:sz="0" w:space="0" w:color="auto" />
</w:tblBorders>
```